# How to render data added with form inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am rendering information from API, but also I need to render new information added with webform.
I made this form to add simple information as the object from the API.
How can I render the data added from this form here?

```
function FormPage({ setData }) {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [id, setId] = useState(0);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const book= { name, description, id}


        fetch('link-from-api', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(book)
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('new book added');            
        })
    }

    return (
        <>     
                    <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <TextField
                                required
                                value={name}
                                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                label="Name" />
                            <TextField
                                required
                                value={description}
                                onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                                label="Description" />
                            <button type="submit" onClick={handleId}> set</button> 
                    </form>
        </>
    );
}

export default FormPage;
```

When I add a new book, I need to see it in this document:

```
function BooksPage() {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('link here')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setBooks(data)
            })
    }, [])


    return (
        <Container>
            <Header />
            {books && 
            <ListBooks props={books} />}
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are 2 ways to handle this, on successful add either make the listing api call again or push new object in the existing array of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the concept called `lifting the state up` here.

Define your state variable `books` in the common parent component of these two components `FormPage` and `BooksPage`

Pass this method to the component FormPage.

```
const addBook = (book) => {
  setBooks(b => [...b, book])
}
```

Call this method at

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const book= { name, description, id}


    fetch('link-from-api', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(book)
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('new book added');
        addBook(book)          
    })
}
```

And pass `books` and `setBooks` to the page BooksPage.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the fetch to a separate function and call again when POST is done

```
function BooksPage() {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

    function fetchBooks() {
        fetch('link here')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setBooks(data)
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchBooks();
    }, [])


    return (
        <Container>
            <Header />
            {books && 
            <ListBooks props={books} />}
            <FormPage fetchBooks={fetchBooks} />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

And in your form:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const book= { name, description, id}


        fetch('link-from-api', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(book)
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('new book added');
            // fetch again
            fetchBooks();            
        })
    }
```